# Opening html file in chrome extension gives me an error

Tags: javascript

when my chrome extension calls this code:

```
var URL = chrome.runtime.getURL('website.html');
var myWindow = window.open(URL, "myWindow");
```

i get this error: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT. I did not find a solution to this, and i dont have adblock installed.

EDIT: Interestingly, when i reload the page that is blocked at first, it loads the website as you would expect it to.

Comment: I am not sure if that's relevant but you can't access local file system from browser using paths. You'll have to use URL of a live site on some server.

Comment: https://www.keycdn.com/support/how-to-solve-err-blocked-by-client

Comment: As already mentioned, i dont have adblock installed